# working with search filters in next js 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

am currently making a ecommerce site search filters like search, price range, etc. but facing some issues.

1. when i search for product, search query appears in url, and worked fine. after that if i put some value inside min, got an error
   [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbUtX.png)
   here is attached code for, filter.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import StarRatings from "react-star-ratings";
import useSearchStore from "@/store/SearchStore";

const Filters = () => {
  const {
    min,
    setMin,
    max,
    setMax,
    category,
    toggleCategory,
    globalQuery,
    setGlobalQuery,
  } = useSearchStore();
  const router = useRouter();

  const checkHandler = (name: any, value: any) => {
    return category.includes(value);
  };

  const handleMinChange = (event: any) => {
    setMin(event.target.valueAsNumber);
    setGlobalQuery();
  };

  const handleMaxChange = (event: any) => {
    setMax(event.target.valueAsNumber);
    setGlobalQuery();
  };

  const handleFilter = () => {
    router.push(`/search?${globalQuery}`);
  };

  const handleCategoryChange = (value: any) => {
    toggleCategory(value);
    setGlobalQuery();
    handleFilter();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setGlobalQuery();
  }, [category]);

  return (
    <aside className="md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 px-4">
      <a
        className="md:hidden mb-5  w-full text-center px-4 py-2 inline-block text-lg text-gray-700 bg-white shadow-sm border border-gray-200 rounded-md hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-600"
        href="#"
      >
        Filter by
      </a>
      <div className="hidden md:block px-6 py-4 border border-gray-200 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
        <h3 className="font-semibold mb-2">Price ($)</h3>
        <div className="grid md:grid-cols-3 gap-x-2">
          <div className="mb-4">
            <input
              name="min"
              className="appearance-none border border-gray-200 bg-gray-100 rounded-md py-2 px-3 hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 w-full"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Min"
              value={min}
              onChange={handleMinChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="mb-4">
            <input
              name="max"
              className="appearance-none border border-gray-200 bg-gray-100 rounded-md py-2 px-3 hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 w-full"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Max"
              value={max}
              onChange={handleMaxChange}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="mb-4" onClick={handleFilter}>
            <button className="px-1 py-2 text-center w-full inline-block text-white bg-blue-600 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-blue-700">
              Go
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="hidden md:block px-6 py-4 border border-gray-200 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
        <h3 className="font-semibold mb-2">Category</h3>

        <ul className="space-y-1">
          <li>
            <label className="flex items-center">
              <input
                name="category"
                type="checkbox"
                value="Electronics"
                defaultChecked={checkHandler("category", "electronics")}
                className="h-4 w-4"
                onChange={() => handleCategoryChange("electronics")}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500"> Electronics </span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label className="flex items-center">
              <input
                name="category"
                type="checkbox"
                value="Laptops"
                className="h-4 w-4"
                defaultChecked={checkHandler("category", "laptops")}
                onChange={() => handleCategoryChange("laptops")}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500"> Laptops </span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label className="flex items-center">
              <input
                name="category"
                type="checkbox"
                value="Toys"
                className="h-4 w-4"
                defaultChecked={checkHandler("category", "toys")}
                onChange={() => handleCategoryChange("toys")}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500"> Toys </span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label className="flex items-center">
              <input
                name="category"
                type="checkbox"
                value="Office"
                className="h-4 w-4"
                defaultChecked={checkHandler("category", "office")}
                onChange={() => handleCategoryChange("office")}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500"> Office </span>
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label className="flex items-center">
              <input
                name="category"
                type="checkbox"
                value="Beauty"
                className="h-4 w-4"
                defaultChecked={checkHandler("category", "beauty")}
                onChange={() => handleCategoryChange("beauty")}
              />
              <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500"> Beauty </span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr className="my-4" />

        <h3 className="font-semibold mb-2">Ratings</h3>
        <ul className="space-y-1">
          <li>
            {[5, 4, 3, 2, 1].map((rating) => (
              <label key={rating} className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  name="ratings"
                  type="checkbox"
                  value={rating}
                  className="h-4 w-4"
                />
                <span className="ml-2 text-gray-500">
                  {" "}
                  <StarRatings
                    rating={rating}
                    starRatedColor="#ffb829"
                    numberOfStars={5}
                    starDimension="20px"
                    starSpacing="2px"
                    name="rating"
                  />{" "}
                </span>
              </label>
            ))}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </aside>
  );
};

export default Filters;
```

here is for page.ts (where searched products appear)

```
"use client";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import ProductList from "../components/products/productList";
async function getData(q: string) {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/search?q=${q}`, {
    next: { revalidate: 600 },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }
  return res.json();
}

const page = async () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const searchQuery = searchParams.get("q");
  const min = searchParams.get("min");
  const max = searchParams.get("max");
  const category = searchParams.get("category");

  const encodedSearchQuery = encodeURI(
    `${searchQuery || ""}${min ? `&min=${min}` : ""}${
      max ? `&max=${max}` : ""
    }${category ? `&category=${category}` : ""}`
  );
  const searchedProducts = await getData(encodedSearchQuery);

  return (
    <div>
      <ProductList data={searchedProducts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

and route.ts file

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { prisma } from "@/libs/prismadb";

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  console.log(" ~ file: route.ts:6 ~ GET ~ searchParams:", searchParams)

  const query = searchParams.get("q");
  const min = searchParams.get("min");
  const max = searchParams.get("max");
  if (typeof query !== "string") {
    throw new Error("invalid query string");
  }

  try {
    const searchedProducts = await prisma.product.findMany({
      where: {
        name: {
          contains: query,
          mode: "insensitive",
        },

        OR: [
          {
            price: {
              lte: Number(max) || 999999,
              gte: Number(min) || 0,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      include: {
        images: true,
        reviews: true,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(searchedProducts);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("failed to fetch data");
  }
}
```

and zustand store for query state management

```
import { create } from "zustand";

interface SearchStoreState {
  searchQuery: string;
  category: string[];
  ratings: number;
  min: number;
  max: number;
  globalQuery: string;
  setsearchQuery: (search: string) => void;
  setRatings: (ratings: number) => void;
  setMin: (min: number) => void;
  setMax: (max: number) => void;
  setGlobalQuery: () => void;
  toggleCategory: (category: string) => void;
  clearFilters: () => void;
}

const useSearchStore = create<SearchStoreState>((set) => ({
  searchQuery: "",
  category: [],
  ratings: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  globalQuery: "",
  setsearchQuery: (search: string) => set({ searchQuery: search }),
  toggleCategory: (category: string) =>
    set((state) => ({
      category: state.category.includes(category)
        ? state.category.filter((c) => c !== category)
        : [...state.category, category],
    })),

  clearFilters: () => set({ category: [] }),
  setRatings: (ratings: number) => set({ ratings }),
  setMin: (min: number) => set({ min }),
  setMax: (max: number) => set({ max }),

  setGlobalQuery: () => {
    set((state) => {
      const { searchQuery, min, max, category, ratings } = state;
  
      const query = `${searchQuery ? `&q=${searchQuery}` : ""}${
        min ? `&min=${min}` : ""
      }${max ? `&max=${max}` : ""}${
        category.length > 0 ? `&category=${category.join("")}` : ""
      }${ratings ? `&ratings=${ratings}` : ""}`;
  
      return { globalQuery: query };
    });
  },
}));

export default useSearchStore;
```

how to make search filters work properly. i have been debugging for 5 days :(

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).